Finding the path/name of modules in an SBT build multi-module project
I am trying to find the path of the modules present inside the SBT built projects.
For example, take this project -> https://github.com/scala/scala
In this project, I executed the dependency tree and got the following list of first level modules.
[info] org.scala-lang:root_2.13:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info] org.scala-lang:scalap:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-compiler-doc:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-compiler-interactive:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-tastytest:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-testkit:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT
[info] org.scala-lang:repl:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-dist:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info] org.scala-lang:tasty:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT
[info] org.scala-lang:scalacheck:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-repl-frontend:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT
[info] org.scala-lang:junit:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-partest:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]

This is the directory structure of the mentioned project (src and test folder)
├── src
│   ├── compiler
│   ├── intellij
│   ├── interactive
│   ├── library
│   ├── library-aux
│   ├── manual
│   ├── partest
│   ├── partest-javaagent
│   ├── reflect
│   ├── repl
│   ├── repl-frontend
│   ├── scaladoc
│   ├── scalap
│   ├── tastytest
│   └── testkit

├── test
│   ├── async
│   ├── benchmarks
│   ├── files
│   ├── instrumented
│   ├── jcstress
│   ├── junit
│   ├── macro-annot
│   ├── osgi
│   ├── scalacheck
│   ├── scaladoc
│   ├── script-tests
│   └── tasty


Main Issue:
As you can see, I cant exactly map the modules straightforwardly to a folder in the directories.
I need
[info] org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]     ->      /path/src/reflect/

[info] org.scala-lang:scalacheck:2.13.11-bin-SNAPSHOT [S]        ->      /path/test/scalacheck/


For now, I had another SBT project as reference, where it was quite straightforward to map the module to source code directory.
Apache Pekko -> https://github.com/apache/pekko
We can just take the artifact name and append it to the base source code path.
Example Code:
String gavid = line.substring(startIndex, line.lastIndexOf(":"));
System.out.println("GAV id: " + gavid);


String[] parts1 = gavid.split(":");
String[] parts2 = parts1[1].split("_");

int hyphenIndex = parts2[0].indexOf('-');
String directory = parts2[0].substring(hyphenIndex + 1);
new_module.setSrcCodePath(object.getSrcCodePath()  + directory + '/');



Are you trying to duplicate SBT's logic in Java, or something?  In general, that won't work without reimplementing SBT.

Yup, it's unclear what's your goal. I would think you can get the desired info by running something like a SBT inspect command

Clone the repo, start sbt, then projects ; show organization ; show name ; show version ; show sourceDirectories. Read it and parse it (or define sbt task which would combine these values and print it somwhere). There is no requirement that there should be any relation with how artifact is named and where its source code is stored. The only source of truth is the build tool so just ask it.

import sbt._
import Keys._

val printModuleDetails = taskKey[Unit]("Prints the artifact name, project ID, and source code location for each module")

printModuleDetails := {
  // Get all projects in the current session
  val allProjects = thisProject.all(ScopeFilter(inAnyProject)).value

  // Iterate over all projects and print their details
  allProjects.foreach { project =>
    println(s"Project ID: ${project.id}")
    println(s"Source Code Location: ${project.base.getAbsolutePath}")

    // Get the artifact name for the project using the correct ProjectRef
    
    //println(s"Artifact Name: ${project.artifactName.getOrElse("Not specified")}")
    //val artifactName = (project / Compile / packageBin / artifactPath).value.getName
    //println(s"Artifact Name: $artifactName")
    //val artifactName = (artifactPath in (project, Compile, packageBin)).value.getName
    //println(s"Artifact Name: $artifactName")

    println() // For readability
  }
}


Although I am able to get project ID and source code location,
I am still unable to find out the artifact name given for each module, as I would have to map it the artifact names elsewhere.

The comment to your answer makes me wonder whether the code in your answer resolves your problem as described in your question, especially since your answer contains only code. Can you [edit] your answer and explain how it resolves your problem?
